# How to clear filtered data using pipe in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I am using this pipe to filter items in the dropdown. Now i want to reset dropdown to default data after item is selected from the filter.

```
@Pipe({name: 'filterdropdownpipe'})
    export class FilterDropdownPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(value: any[], filter: string): Object[] {
        filter = filter ? filter.toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
        return filter ? value.filter((item: any) =>
          (item.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filter)) || filter === '') : value;
      }
    }


<div class="filter-div" *ngFor="let institution of institutions | filterdropdownpipe: searchInstitute">
                    <ul class="drop-list drop-list-2">
                      <li [ngClass]="institution.highlighted ? 'highlighted-filter-item' : 'normal-filter-item'"
                          (click)="onInstitutionSelection(institution)">{{institution.name}}
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you adjust your pipe a little bit, you can achieve this by returning all values when your filter based on an empty string (which you have tried to do, but I think there is a small bug there). You also need to have the empty string option in your drop-down.

`filter = filter ? filter.toLocaleLowerCase() : ""; // changed from null to ""`

Also remember to update your search term:

Inside your `onInstitutionSelection()`-method, set `searchInstitute = ""`

Comment: This doesnt work. I want to refill dropdown with all values on (click)="onInstitutionSelection(institution)"

Comment: can you do a: `searchInstitute = "" ` inside your onInstitutionSelection-method?

Answer (score 0):

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'searchPipe'
})
```

HTML

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="search text goes here" [value]="searchText">
<button [hidden]="!searchText"  (click)="searchText = ''">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Where are you using the pipe on the html?

Answer (score -1):

.html

```
<input [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="search text goes here" [value]="searchText" >
<button [hidden]="!searchText"  (click)="clearText()">Clear</button>
```

.ts

```
clearText(){
    this.searchText = '';
}
```

Comment: OR you can use this

 <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="search text goes here" [value]="searchText" >

            <button [hidden]="!searchText"  (click)="searchText = ''"">Clear</button>